# RealmSwiftをCocoaPodsで導入したい

Tags: realm, cocoapods

xcode7.2、realm-swift-0.96-2.3の環境です。

ターミナルで`sudo gem install cocoapods`と入力してインストールし`pod setupSuccessfully installed cocoapods-0.39.0`となりました。

続いて`pod setup`と入力、`Setting up CocoaPods master repo、Setup completedxcode`と出力されました。

そこで`$ pod install`と入力したら、`command not found`と出力されたので、再度 `$ pod install`と入力したら、

```
[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
```

と出力されました。Xcodeプロジェクトのフオルダがあるデイレクトリに移動しても同じ結果でした。

RealmSwiftをSwiftのプロジェクトで使えるようにするにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

一般的なCocoaPodsによるライブラリの導入方法の話になると思います。

[公式サイト](https://cocoapods.org/)のGET STARTEDや、CocoaPodsについて解説しているサイトを読んでみてください。

Swiftのプロジェクトに対してライブラリを導入するには、最初にSwiftのプロジェクトを作る必要があります。そして、対象の`xcodeproj`のあるディレクトリに`Podfile`を作成します。

RealmSwiftの場合の記述方法は、[公式の導入方法](https://realm.io/jp/docs/swift/latest/)を参考にしてみてください。例えば以下のようなテキストファイルになります。

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'ターゲット名' do
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

作成方法は、テキストエディタでも何でも良いです。

ターゲット名はXcodeでプロジェクトの情報を表示した際に、**TARGETS** に表示されているものとなります。

`use_frameworks!`の指定は、Swift用のライブラリを導入する際に必須となるもので、従来のStatic Link Libraryではなく、Dynamic Frameworkを生成してリンクします。ブリッジングヘッダなしで`import`でライブラリが使えます（ただしiOS7以前で動作しなくなります）。

あとは`Podfile`のあるディレクトリで、

```
pod install
```

を実行し、しばらく待つと作成される`.xcworkspace`ファイルからワークスペースを開きます。

Comment: podfileを作成して installがお陰様で出来ました。.xcworkspaceは、Xcodeプロジェクトと同じディレクトリに作成されるのでしょうか。申し訳ありません。しばらく待ってもどこにできているのか、わかりませんでした。また、[!] Oh no, an error occurred.Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=File+exists+-...。
If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods../new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods..CONTRIBUTING.mdDon't forget to anonymize any private data
という、エラーのようなものがシュミレーターに出ましたがどのような問題があるのでしょうか。

Comment: XCodeと同じプロジェクトに作られます。シミュレータにエラーが表示されているという状況は分かりかねますが、`xcworkspace`が生成されないということは、`pod install`に失敗していますね。

Comment: Podfileに文法エラーがあると思いますね。作成されたPodfileの内容をそのまま載せてください。

Comment: podfileを見直したら誤りがあったので訂正してからpodinstallを実行したところ、xcworkspaceが生成されていました。お世話様でした。